# How to get sum of GridView column's time values

Tags: c#, gridview, devexpress, summary, time-format

I try to get the summary for the specific GridView's column and pass it to the TextEdit.
The display format is time `HH:mm.ff` (`22:40`, `10:30`)

[image: Summary Item settings]
[image: My results]

Comment: Didn't quiet understand what you are asking for..Can u clarify ?

Comment: I'm doing Click GridView and turn on the properties and OptionsView in ShowFooter activated I'm trying columns cell format changed summaryitem to the displayformat for calculate columns cell.

Comment: If you are a beginner with c# , then i suggest you rather [join the chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168138/begin-with-vb)where i can help , because i cannot post an answer to this qs as it is not an ideal one ;(

Comment: what format can I use to aggregate the format of the columns? I just want to know what format to use for the calculation.

Comment: Give an example and an expected result

Comment: I want to get the sum of the hours HH: mm format in a GridView column. For example 08:00,02:00,04:00,08:30,01:00= 23:30 Total Hours

Comment: do u want this to happen inside the gridview itself ?? ..Dunno if it would work on devexpress gridview or not but try splitting the hour strings using `;` , then convert them to integers then sum up .. then finally add the summed up value to the grid.... Hope it helps :)

Comment: If you are using DevExpress know you the ShowFooter and summaryitem properties. I think it's easier. but need the time format :)